# Declarar Variable Tipo Generica

Tags: java

Quiero que cuando declare la variable2 sea el tipo de variable que asigne sobre `<Pcambiar>`

En cursos lo vi asi pero no se en que me equivoco

```
class Hola <Pcambiar>{

public Hola(Pcambiar variable1) {
    Pcambiar variable2 = 5; ////aqui mi da error

    System.out.println("esta es la variable:"+variable1);


}
```

}

Comment: Hola,
Yo de java ni idea pero te doy un pista a ver si buscan por google te apañas un poco mas.

En tu código defines una clase genérica pero luego en el método el trato es de clase "concreta"

es decir tu le dices  "
class Hola<T> { 

public void Hola(T algo)
{
        algo = 2;  // <-  Algo ya no es genérico, aquí le dices que es integer
}

 }"

para hacer lo que quieres hacer, necesitas convertir "algo" a un tipo utilizando un casting. 

((int)algo) = 2;

en c# le puedes especificar que parta de algún tipo base
class Hola<T> where T: Persona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la variable es genérica, no puedes asignarle un valor aleatorio. En este caso, el tipo `Pcambiar` va a depender de lo que necesite la clase. Imagina que no usaras genéricos y en su lugar debas utilizar una clase real como `String` en lugar de donde está `Pcambiar`, entonces el código luciría así:

```
public Hola(String variable1) {
    //Error aquí. No se puede asignar un entero (int) a un String
    String variable2 = 5;
    System.out.println("esta es la variable: " + variable1);
}
```

La idea de los genéricos es que ayuden a definir métodos que pueden ser utilizados para muchas clases o para un grupo de clases que cumplan cierto criterio como extender de una interfaz o clase abstracta. Además, para asignar el valor de un genérico, deberías realizarlo en el constructor o en un método `set` mediante una variable del mismo tipo del genérico.

Código de ejemplo basado en tu código actual:

```
public class Hola <Pcambiar>{
    public Hola(Pcambiar variable1) {
        Pcambiar variable2 = variable1;
        System.out.println("esta es la variable: " + variable2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args]) {
        //mira que el argumento sea del tipo de clase que estamos enviando
        new Hola<String>("Jaime");
        //los genéricos son solo para clases, no para primitivos
        new Hola<Integer>(5);
        //igual aquí, por ello debemos colocar 10L y no 10
        //sino dará error de compilación
        new Hola<Long>(10L);
        //funciona con cualquier clase
        //agrega el import adecuado: import java.math.BigDecimal
        new Hola<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal("10.0"));
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
esta es la variable: Jaime
esta es la variable: 5
esta es la variable: 10
esta es la variable: 10.0
```

Comment: esto es justo lo que nesecitaba saber "Además, para asignar el valor de un genérico, deberías realizarlo en el constructor o en un método set mediante una variable del mismo tipo del genérico."
pero solo se puede con un mismo generico, porque no con cualquier otra variable?

Comment: @JaimeSaiag la respuesta a esa pregunta está en la primera parte de la respuesta. Eso explica todo. Imagina que tu genérico soporte cadenas pero lo quieres inicializar con un número, no se puede.

Comment: pero si al generico lo voy a volver una variable Int entonces si deberia de funcionar si pongo un numero?

Comment: Si es genérico entonces no puedes asumir que va a ser un entero. Para ello, mejor utilizas enteros en lugar de genéricos. Lo que podrías hacer quizás es que si sabes que todos tus genéricos deben ser números puedes usar `<T extends Number>` y así puedes saber que tu genérico solo va a representar números y va a soportar operaciones numéricas. Pero igual, lo que quieres hacer es inicializar tu variable genérica (referencia) con un primitivo (`int`), lo cual **no es viable**.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te estas desviando un poco del concepto de genéricos y sus funcionalidades. Te recomiendo leer esta publicación:
[Uso de Java Generics](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/uso-de-java-generics/)